# Verification URL for Discord JS

Tags: javascript, mongoose, discord.js

Would it be possible to create a one-click URL verification system in Discord JS. Essentially, when you signup for my service you get an email with a verification URL that when clicked adds you to the discord server, gives you the appropriate role, and adds you to my Mongoose database. I've seen this kind of system done for regular applications, but never through discord.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the discord OAUTH2 system to gain access to add the user to guilds automatically. You can create a 2 stepped system first it would verify the user in the local database and then redirect them to the generated OAUTH2 URL
https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2
[image]